# Array list index out of range in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    z: int = 1
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            if z % 2 != 0:
                vocde.append(line)
                z = z + 1

            if z % 2 == 0:
                vocen.append(line)
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

I´ve got a txt file with 4 lines the odd number is always a german word and the even number is a english word.
I would like to have in one array all the english words and in the other all the german words.
Because i would like to implement in my vocabulary trainer a function to import own vocabulary by a text file.

That is the error Code : IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you update `z` only when it is odd, but `z` should be updated at every iteration.
What happens is that `z` gets to be `2` and stays `2`, so only the first line lands in `vocde`, while all other lines (actually all the lines, because upon reaching the second condition `z` has been already *updated*) land in `vocen`.
After the loop, when you try to access the second element of `vocde` with `vocde[1]` (the first being `vocde[0]`) there are just not enough elements for that to succeed.

The simplest working modification to your code would then be:

```
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    z: int = 1
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            if z % 2 != 0:
                vocde.append(line)
            if z % 2 == 0:
                vocen.append(line)
            z += 1
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

---

On the other hand, it would be a bit more elegant to write with an `if`-`else` construct rather than `if condition` and `if not condition`. Also, you do not really make use of the value of `z`, you only need a "flip-flop" variable. Finally, in both branches you perform fundamentally the same operation (`list.append()`) to a different target, so all this can be written a bit more concisely with a ternary operator.

```
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    is_de = True
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            (vocde if is_de else vocen).append(line)
            is_de = not is_de
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

Answer (score 0):

`z` must be incremented when it is even or odd, but your code only changes it when it is odd. Also, your second `if` can be changed to just `else`.

```py
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    z: int = 1
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            if z % 2 != 0:
                vocde.append(line)
            else:
                vocen.append(line)
            z = z + 1
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

You can also just put `z` in the loop to avoid having to increment it:

(As @norok2 pointed out, the conditions should be inverted since the enumeration starts with 0.)

```py
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for z, line in enumerate(ins):
            if z % 2 == 0:
                vocde.append(line)
            else:
                vocen.append(line)
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

The conditional can be further shortened using a ternary:

```py
def load():
    vocen = []
    vocde = []
    with open("en_de.txt", "r") as ins:
        for z, line in enumerate(ins):
           vocen.append(line) if z % 2 else vocde.append(line)
    print(vocde[1])
    print(vocen[1])
    print("Du hast erfolgreich deine Datei geladen")
```

Comment: The second suggestion will not work correctly, because the code is relying on `z` being `1` in the first iteration. You can either flip the condition or let `z` start from `1` with `enumerate(ins, 1)`.